# ¿Cómo realizo el testing de este programa en java?

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo este código que llama un archivo txt, lo almacena en un ArrayList, y finalmente desordenada y ordena todos los caracteres del mismo.

Necesito testear los metodos de ordenar y desordenar, como pruebas unitarias.

```
public static void main (String args []) throws IOException{
String linea = "PALABRA2.TXT";
ArrayList<String> archivoLista = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Archivo.txt"))) 
{
while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(linea);
    archivoLista.add(linea); /* Agrega la Línea leída a la lista */
  }
}
System.out.println("LISTA DESORDENADA: ");
Collections.shuffle(archivoLista); /* Modifica Orden*/
/* Imprimir en una sola línea */
for(String temp: archivoLista){    
System.out.println(temp); 
}
/* Ordenar nuevamente*/
System.out.println("LISTA ORDENADA: ");
Collections.sort(archivoLista);

for(String temp: archivoLista){

System.out.println(temp);
}}}
```

Al querer realizar las pruebas unitarias me quedo trabado:

```
@Test
public void TestDesordenar() {
    String line = "Archivo.txt";
ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("archivo.txt"))) 
{
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    fileList.add(line); /* Agrega línea leída a la lista */
  }
}
System.out.println("LISTA DESORDENADA ");
Collections.shuffle(fileList);
assert.
}

@Test
public void TestOrdenar() {

}
```

¿De qué forma los puedo hacer?

Comment: La pregunta no tiene mucho sentido. Si lo que quieres es ordenar por el método de la burbuja, eso no tiene que ver con hacer tests. Escribe el código que has probado para ordenar y explica qué problemas has encontrado. Si lo que quieres es hacer un test de un código, el código a testear ya debería estar escrito.

Comment: Necesito ordenar, y luego hacer el test de ese metodo y el de desordenar también. Son dos cosas distintas las que necesito realizar.

Comment: Pues entonces son dos preguntas, en cada una de las cuales explicas lo que has hecho y que problemas te encuentras. Estás de suerte, este mes tienes que pagar lo mismo por una pregunta que por dos... :-)

Comment: Modifique mi pregunta, para dar más sentido a lo que necesito. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema principal es que el programa está mal diseñado, no es nada modular. Tal como está escrito sólo te sirve para ordenar los `String`que aparecen en un archivo en un formato específico en una ubicación específica, y para nada más.

Debería dividirse en partes<sup>1</sup>, con cada parte haciendo una única cosa:

- La primera lee un archivo<sup>2</sup> y devuelve un `List<String>` con los contenidos. Le da igual para qué se utilizan los datos.
- La segunda realiza la ordenación de un `List<String>` que se le pasa por parámetro y devuelve un List ordenado. Le da igual de dónde vienen los datos y qué se hará con el resultado.
- La tercera hace el inverso, recibe un `List<String>` y devuelve un `List<String` desordenado. Le da igual de dónde vienen los datos y qué se hará con el resultado.
- La cuarta recibe un `List<Stream>` y un `OutputStream` y escribe la lista en el stream. Le da igual de dónde vienen los datos.

Una vez hecho esto, tienes mucha más flexibilidad, lo que hace la creación de tests más sencilla. Por ejemplo, para probar la ordenación:

```
@Test
public void testOrdenar() {
   // Preparar los valores para la brueba
   List<String> valores =
      Arrays.asList("valor100", "valor020", "valor35");

   // Ejecutar el método
   MiClaseDeOrdenar miClase =
      new MiClaseDeOrdenar();
   List<String> resultado =
      miClase.ordenar(valores);

   // Comprobar que se devuelve un resultado
   assertNotNull(
      "Resultado es null", resultado);
   // Comprobar que hay 3 valores en el resultado
   assertEquals(
      "No hay 3 elementos", 3, resultado.size());
   // Comprobar que cada elemento está donde toca
   assertEquals(
      "El elemento 1 no está ordenado", "valor020", resultado.get(0));
   assertEquals(
      "El elemento 2 no está ordenado", "valor035", resultado.get(1));
   assertEquals(
      "El elemento 3 no está ordenado", "valor100", resultado.get(2));
 }
```

Si no lo haces por partes, para hacer un test tendrías que sobreescribir el archivo indicado con los valores de prueba (machacando lo que hubiera allí) y luego leer dicho archivo para comprobar los valores.

---

<sup>1</sup>En teoría, cada "parte" es una clase diferente (principio de responsabilidad única).

<sup>2</sup>O mejor aún, de un `InputStream` que se le pasa como parámetro, y así puedes leer los datos de un archivo, de un socket, etc...

Comment: Muchas gracias. Disculpe, pero ¿de que manera paso por parametro el ArrayList de la primera clase hacia las 3 últimas clases?

Comment: Pues desde donde necesites ejecutar esa lógica... por ejemplo desde el `main` (que también debería estar en otra clase separada).